# Preventing selecting duplicate entries from drop down list - excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have created a drop-down list ( 50 date values) in one column ( column A  of sheet 2). Now I want to use the Sheet2 values in Sheet1 to create a drop-down list in column D, using the Data validation Tool as List.

I'm trying to make sure that no one will not duplicate the entries from the drop-down list in any of the cells in column D -
For example: if I choose from the drop-down list "November 17 2023" in Shee1!D2 cell, no one should be able to select the same date("November 17 2023") to any of the cells in "Shee1! column D".

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Excellent answer for my issue, but I'm not planning to delete my post as it may help others to work as a pointer